# what is mean by app.set, app.use, app.enable?

Tags: node.js, express

I am new in node.js, and found some statement most places and I also use these statements but I don't know the exact meaning of these.

```
app.disable('etag')
app.set('view engine', 'es6')
app.use(parallel(middlewares))
```

please some explain `app.disable`, `app.set` and `app.use`. please not explain `view engine` or about `es6` etc.

I mean why we use `app.disable`, `app.set`, `app.use` or what it dose?

Comment: The real question is, "What is app?" It seems obvious from the [express documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html) that this is the API object for the Express framework. So, please consult their documentation for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html):

`app.disable` and `app.set` are about manipulating global state (imagine a dictionary).  The former sets a given key to 'false' while the latter sets it to an arbitrary value.

`app.use` on the other hand, mounts a middleware function into the request flow, which is how you inject logic into your express application.

These are all concepts that you should spend time reading the docs to more fully understand.